# pyspark function understanding - conversion factor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm coding in PySpark on Apache Spark, Databricks.

I have a DataFrame **DF** and the DataFrame contains the following columns [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J].

The following validates the dataframe has the required columns

```
has_columns(very_large_dataframe, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'])
```

There is a requirement to apply conversion factor of 2.5 to Column F i.e. Value 2, conversion factor 2.5 = 5.

The full context of the code is as follows:

> very_large_dataframe 250 GB of CSV files from client which must have
> only 10 columns [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J], [A, B] contains string
> data [C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J], contains decimals with precision 5,
> scale 2 (i.e. 125.75) [A, B, C, D, E], should not be null [F, G, H, I,
> J] should may be null

```
very_large_dataset_location = '/Sourced/location_1'
very_large_dataframe = spark.read.csv(very_large_dataset_location, header=True, sep="\t")
```

**validate column count**

```
if column_count(very_large_dataframe) != 10:
        raise Exception('Incorrect column count: ' + column_count(very_large_dataframe))
```

**validate that dataframe has all required columns**

```
has_columns(very_large_dataframe, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'])
```

However, I have never come across applying a conversion factor to column.

Is anyone familiar with applying a conversion factor with PySpark? (or any language for that matter)

Comment: Can you explain what is a "_conversion factor of 2.5 to Column F_"? Please add example input and expected output

Comment: First, I would like to know if someone has come across the term 'Conversion factor' with PySpark? I haven't got a clue what Conversion Factor is?

Comment: Isn't conversion factor just multiplication?

Comment: Hi Alex, I didn't even think of **Conversion Factor** being multiplication, so even that suggestion has helped. I just dont understand it, in connection to the task of applying conversion factor of 2.5 to Column F i.e. Value 2, conversion factor 2.5 = 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion factor is the number that is multipled by, for example 2 x 2.5 = 5, so it translated the 2 is multipled by 2.5 times.

So the conversion / multiplication factor of 2 is 2.5.

This is my understanding.